# How to kill and event and attach one right after it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button in my form, when the user clicks on it, it checks to see if the user has selected any item or not, if not, then alerts the user.

But if true, then the items get hidden and a new set gets generated; still, the button is fixed. Now, if the user clicks on it, it checks based on the criteria and events attached to it for previous set, while I have changed the set and need to set a new "click" event and consequently a new condition.

I have user the following code to turn off the primary event and assign a new one, however, it does not work and still relies on the previous event:

```
//***** SELECTING CHILD CATEGORIES *****/

$('body').off('click', nextbt, function(){
        nextbt.click(function(){    
     if(child_cat.children('.active-child').length == 0)
     {  
        /** ALERTIFY **/    
    //      alertify.set({labels : {'ok': 'تایید'}});           
    ///     alertify.alert("Select a sub-category please");
          /** END OF ALERTIFY **/   
     }else{ // the user has selected one cateogry
        $('.new-item-cats-list-holder').fadeOut(500);
        $('.big-loader').show();// set the loader
        $.ajax({

        });
     }
    });
});
```

And here is the primary main event attached to the button and `$(document).ready()`:

```
$('.next-stage-bottom').on('click', function(){
  // when clicked on the next bottom
  if($('.new-item-cat-item-active').length > 0)
  {

    $('.new-item-cats-list-holder').hide()
    $('.new-item-cats-list-holder').empty();
    $('.big-loader').show();
    $.ajax({
        url : base_path('ajax/get_cat_children/'),
        type: "POST",
        data : ({'get_children' : true, 'parent_id' : selected_cat}),
        success : function(msg){                   
            $('.new-item-cats-list-holder').show();
            $('.new-item-cats-list-holder').append(msg);                    
            $('.big-loader').hide();
        },
    });
  }// end of length if
  else
  {
  /** ALERTIFY **/  
    alertify.set({labels : {'ok': 'تایید'}});           
    alertify.alert("Select a cateogry first");
  /** END OF ALERTIFY **/   
  }
});// end of click event for button
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two useful ways to use `.off()`.

1. Leave out the function argument. It will remove all handlers for the event.
2. Use a named function when binding the handler, and then use the same name with `.off()`. This way, it can find the matching handler and remove it.

In your code, you're using an anonymous function, and each anonymous function is different, so it doesn't find the handler to remove.